# Accessing from a parent class

Tags: java, inheritance, object

I have a bit of a problem that I can't seem to code my way out of for the moment.

I have 2 classes, one is an abstract class that its children inherit from, and the children extend that class.

So it's something like this:

```
abstract class foo implements Runnable{
    int whatever;
    int whatever2;

    public void doStuff(){

        //need value from child class here -- should be 100
}

public class bar extends foo{
    private int ID = 100;

    //getter here
}
```

The reason to use a parent class is to unify my constructors / serialization methods to accept tons of different classes that all have similar data but with wildly different values.

Comment: Java conventions mean that class names should start with a capital letter, e.g. `Bar` and `Foo`.  It might seem like a minor thing but reading your code, it feels surprisingly... odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a method:

```
public abstract class Foo {

    public void doStuff(){
        int id = getID(); // <==== get the ID
    }

    public abstract int getID();
}

public class Bar extends Foo {

    private int ID = 100;

    public int getID() {
      return ID;
    }
}
```

(Adjust the visibility of `getID()` as appropriate for your use case.)